# is there lm(.~x,data)? how can i run many y in lm formula

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I know about `lm(y~. , data)`
 but I'm wondering about the opposite direction

If I want to put multiple y to lm function, how should I do that? Using for? loop?

My desired result is getting each p-value and beta value of Y. There is just one X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lm` supports a matrix on the LHS of the formula:

```
f <- as.formula(sprintf("cbind(%s) ~ Species", 
                         paste(names(iris)[names(iris) != "Species"], collapse = ", ")))
#cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species
summary(lm(f, data = iris))
```